# I need to make a calculated bonus print out at the end of my code but I can not seem to figure out how. How would I go about this?

Tags: python

For example, if I enter 10000, then enter the number 1. The output is 10125.0. I need to be able to print like so:

```
The raise is: 125
Salary is now: 10125.0
```

```
current_sal = int(input("Please enter your current salary: "))
employee_rank = -1
int(employee_rank)
while int(employee_rank) <0 or int(employee_rank) >5:
employee_rank = input("Please enter your employee rank: ")
sal_plus_raise = 0
if employee_rank == '5':
sal_plus_raise = current_sal + (.035 * current_sal)
elif employee_rank == '4':
sal_plus_raise = current_sal + (.0325 * current_sal)
elif employee_rank == '3':
sal_plus_raise = current_sal + (.025 * current_sal)
elif employee_rank == '2':
sal_plus_raise = current_sal + (.02 * current_sal)
elif employee_rank == '1':
sal_plus_raise = current_sal + (.0125 * current_sal)
else:
sal_plus_raise = current_sal

print ("Salary is: ",sal_plus_raise)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your needs it makes sense to calculate the `salary_raise` and then use that to return both the `total_salary` and the `raise` itself.

A modified version of your code just that change, and a few things removed that I don't think you need (based on the description given):

```py
current_sal = int(input("Please enter your current salary: "))
employee_rank = input("Please enter your employee rank: ")
salary_raise = 0
if employee_rank == '5':
    salary_raise = .035 * current_sal
elif employee_rank == '4':
    salary_raise = .0325 * current_sal
elif employee_rank == '3':
    salary_raise = .025 * current_sal
elif employee_rank == '2':
    salary_raise = .02 * current_sal
elif employee_rank == '1':
    salary_raise = .0125 * current_sal

print("The raise is: ", salary_raise)
print("Salary is now: ", current_sal + salary_raise)
```